# Academic edition CPLEX and docplex

Tags: python, mips, cplex, docplex

I have two questions. First, even I upgrade my CPLEX from trial to academic version still in my IBM page it is shown as trial edition. Second, related to this (I guess) I am getting error while trying to solve my model with Python. Can someone give me the instructions what should I do regarding to this? Please see error below regarding python.

```
-- cannot find parameters matching version: , using: 22.1.1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karaba02\PycharmProjects\ergoModel\random_data_generator.py", line 179, in <module>
    output = ergonomic_operator_assignment.ergonomic_math_model_solver(data_name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\karaba02\PycharmProjects\ergoModel\ergonomic_operator_assignment.py", line 148, in ergonomic_math_model_solver
    erg_model.print()
  File "C:\Users\karaba02\PycharmProjects\ergoModel\ergonomic_operator_assignment.py", line 112, in print
    self.solution = self.ergoModel.solve(log_output=True)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\karaba02\PycharmProjects\ergoModel\venv\Lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\model.py", line 4835, in solve
    return self.fatal("Cannot solve model: no CPLEX runtime found.")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\karaba02\PycharmProjects\ergoModel\venv\Lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\model.py", line 1080, in fatal
    self._error_handler.fatal(msg, args)
  File "C:\Users\karaba02\PycharmProjects\ergoModel\venv\Lib\site-packages\docplex\mp\error_handler.py", line 210, in fatal
    raise DOcplexException(resolved_message)
docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: Cannot solve model: no CPLEX runtime found.
```

I have tried upgrade the academic version of CPLEX and make connection with python. It seems something related to enviroment but I don't know how I can solve this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is regarding the working environment instate of code.

Comment: Did you follow the manual which comes with your cplex distribution (e.g. running setup.py within it)?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't work. I solve this with the following link. I will share if someone needs it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3tIPQn6z5U